# Is it OK for several paths to share the same ETag?

Tags: http, http-caching

I run a real-time image resizing server, that acts as a proxy between the browser and the server owning the original image:

```
Browser <=> Resize server <=> Origin server
```

I can request an image on the resizing server, with different parameters:

```
/images/kitten.jpg?w=400&h=300
/images/kitten.jpg?w=800&h=600
```

Both requests will fetch the same file `/images/kitten.jpg` on the origin server, but yield a different version (size) of this image.

Now I want to implement caching. Say the origin server sends an `ETag` header:

```
ETag: "13456789abcdef"
```

If I just forward the unmodified `ETag` along with my resized image, the browser will cache two different images, on two different paths, with the same `ETag`.

Now I can happily forward any `If-None-Match` header from the browser to the origin server, and react to a `304 Not Modified` by responding with a `304` in return.

But **could it be a problem when two paths on my web server, serving different content, share the same `ETag`?**

I've implemented it successfully so far, everything seems to work as expected. I just want to be sure that I have not overlooked something, and that there is no side effect of having several paths sharing the same `ETag` in the browser's cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a problem. ETags are per request URI.